# Auto-translate messages in LuisDialog by overriding MessageReceived

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to create a `LuisDialog` where all messages from the user will be auto-translated into the language that my LUIS app understands.

To do that, I am overriding the `LuisDialog.MessageReceived()` method.

I auto-translate the message into my language, but where I'm stuck is how to update the value of `IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>.Text` so that it is transparently accessible to intent-based methods inside the dialog.

```
[Serializable]
class LuisDialogAutoTranslated<T> : LuisDialog<T>
{
    protected override async Task MessageReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> msg)
    {
        var activity = await msg;

        activity.Text = await new CognitiveTranslator().TranslateToCurrentLanguage(activity.Text);

        //????
        //how to replace the value of IMessageActivity.Text
        //inside the IAwaitable msg?
        //????

        await base.MessageReceived(context, msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of overriding the `MessageReceived` I would recommend you to override the [`GetLuisQueryTextAsync`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/8f0d6bbc1ef0fcef99b04560391384aba8fcde15/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs#L259), which basically receives the message and return the text that will be passed to LUIS ([see here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/8f0d6bbc1ef0fcef99b04560391384aba8fcde15/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs#L202)).

If you still want to override the `MessageReceived`, then you will have create an `Awaitable<T>` using `Awaitable.FromItem<IMessageActivity>(activity)` as shown in the code below.

```
var activity = await msg;

activity.Text = await new CognitiveTranslator().TranslateToCurrentLanguage(activity.Text);

msg = Awaitable.FromItem<IMessageActivity>(activity);

await base.MessageReceived(context, msg);
```